# .htaccess: Want query string added to 301 Redirect to same url

Tags: .htaccess, query-string, infinite-loop

Example: When someone visits this URL

http://example.com/site/register

I'd like this query string to be automatically added:

http://example.com/site/register?destination=thankyou

I've tried the following in my .htaccess file:

Redirect 301 /site/register /site/register?destination=thankyou

But this creates an infinite redirect loop.

I've crawled the web for hours for a solution but to no avail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but you are catching ALL requests to `/site/register`, and then expect a request to `/site/register` not to be caught? that's impropable to work. instead maybe use PHP or just redirect to `/site/register_thanks_message?...` or something

Answer (score 0):

if `register` is PHP, use something like:

```
<?php
  if(!array_key_exists('destination',$_GET))
    header('Location: '.http_build_query(
        array_merge($_GET,array('destination'=>'thankyou')));
```